# How to automate automatic changing dynamic values with selenium rc and java

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testng

i am stuck with a situation where i have two textboxes with an (+) operator between it, now the values in these text boxes changes automaticalyy, user has to sum these values and write the sum and press nexxt to go to next page., as the values are changing i am not able to use selenium.getvalue evry time , can anyone suggest how to handle this.I am using selenium rc with testng , eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String tb1=selenium.getAttribute("xpath to ur textbox 1/@value");
String tb2=selenium.getAttribute("xpath to ur textbox 2/@value");
int FinalValue = Integer.parseInt(tb1)+Integer.parseInt(tb2);
```

Hope this would help you.

Comment: Thanks , this helps , but one doubt why wouldnt the se.getvalue work every time in this situation , any particular reason for that.?

Comment: I am not sure this may happen due to any issue specific to your case.I too face such issues somtimes and then I opt for getAttribute method,Thats why I recommended the same to you.